# Number of ways to divide a group of $8$ men and $4$ women.

Tags: combinatorics

There are $12$ people: $8$ men and $4$ women. I want to divide them into $4$ groups of $2$ men and $1$ woman each. How many possible configurations do I have?

My solution to this question was:

"First of all, I suppose that each man and woman is distinguishable and I suppose the same for the four groups.

For the men:

I have ${8}\choose{2}$ possible combinations for the first group. After choosing a combination for the first group, I have ${6}\choose{2}$ possible combinations for the second group. After I choose the combinations for the first and second groups, I have ${4}\choose{2}$ possible combinations for the third group and after I choose the combination for the first, second and third group, I have  ${2}\choose{2}$ possible combinations for the last group.Thus, if I choose a combination for the first $3$ groups, I automatically choose a combination for the last group.

I have a total of ${8}\choose{2}$$ {6}\choose{2}$ ${4}\choose{2}$${2}\choose{2}$ possible ways to separate the $8$ men into $4$ groups of $2$ men each.

But, I dont need to start choosing a combination of $2$ men for the first group and after that for the second, etc. I can start with the third group,  for example. Then, I have a total of $4!$ permutations of the order of the groups, giving a total number of ways:

$4!$${8}\choose{2}$$ {6}\choose{2}$ ${4}\choose{2}$${2}\choose{2}$

Following the same argument, we have, for the women:
$4!$${4}\choose{1}$$ {3}\choose{1}$ ${2}\choose{1}$${1}\choose{1}$ $=4!4!$ number of ways.

The total number of ways is, then: $4!4!4!$${8}\choose{2}$$ {6}\choose{2}$ ${4}\choose{2}$${2}\choose{2}$."

I'm not confident about this solution, specially about the $4!$ in front of the binomial coefficients.

Some of my friends believe that the correct answer is simply 
${8}\choose{2}$ $\cdot$ ${4}\choose{1}$

I'm afraid that both solutions might be wrong. So, how would you solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Since each group has precisely one woman in it, you can index each group by the woman it contains. Then you have to choose two me for each woman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your reasons for multiplying by $4!$ are a little confused. An easier way to think of it is this:

As there are four women, and four groups each of which contains one woman, we can "label" each group by the woman in it.

Woman one has ${8}\choose{2}$ ways to choose her two partners.

Woman two has ${6}\choose{2}$ ways to choose hers.

Woman three has ${4}\choose{2}$ ways to choose hers.

Woman four is left with the remaining two men (${2}\choose{2}$ = $1$).

So there are ${8}\choose{2}$× ${6}\choose{2}$×${4}\choose{2}$× ${2}\choose{2}$ combinations.

If the order of the groups is important, then we can multiply by the $4!$ ways of ordering them.

Answer (score 4):

You had the right solution, almost. Call the women A, B, C, D. Woman A can choose her partners in $\binom{8}{2}$ ways. For each such way, woman B can choose her partners in $\binom{6}{2}$ ways. And then woman C has $\binom{4}{2}$ choices. Multiply, and it's over.